# Do we Need Pay Tax for Mining for US Govt

Tags: mining-pools, taxes, usa

Do you need to pay Taxes for US Govt for doing Bitcion  Mining.??

I am in Singapore and mining through one of my friend in US.
Will the US Governement will issue TAX on My Name..?? Is it Legit ..?

If so, How much Taxation..?
Does Univted States TAx Revenue Board send the TAX Invioce on my Name

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Do you need to pay Taxes for US Govt for doing Bitcion Mining.?**

You are not liable for income tax because:

- You are not a US citizen and
- You are not working in the USA.

Someone in the USA who is selling you a service might be required to charge sales-tax (though that sort of tax is often not applied to foreign sales).

> **Does Univted States TAx Revenue Board send the TAX Invioce on my Name**

As far as I know, there is no USA government branch named "United States Tax Revenue Board".

The USA Internal Revenue Service (IRS) would not charge you personally for sales tax. So far as I know, US sales taxes are a state tax not a federal tax

---

## Scams

When buying "mining services" be aware that, unless you have a really good understanding of how bitcoin mining works, you are likely to be the victim of a fraudster.

One of the things fraudsters do is repeatedly *invent* superficially plausible (but actually false) reasons for you to send them money.